# What will be the output of String.substring(String.length)?

Tags: java, string

```
public class Str {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "abcde";
        String s = str.substring(str.length());
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

The index of character 'e' is 4, but I am trying to get the whole string of length 5. If I execute the code above, why it is not throwing the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: Indexing in java starts from 0

Comment: Array starts at 0 ``str.substring(str.length()-1)`` !

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.com)

Comment: @huntsMan,  str.substring(str.length()-1) will give complete String but str.length() will return length as 5 but there is no 5th index it should throw Exception right?

Comment: @YallalingKolkur its has indexing like the indexing of array it starts always with zero but the length is different it gives the human terms for it will be easy to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JavaDoc for [String.substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) states:

> [throws] IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.

Since your beginIndex is equal to the length of the string it is a valid value and `substring()` returns an empty string.

Comment: In this case what will be the value of that beginIndex

Comment: @YallalingKolkur If you call substring with only 1 argument, this argument is the start Index, not the end Index

Comment: @YallalingKolkur there are two `substring()` methods. One takes two arguments: a `beginIndex` and an `endIndex`. The other takes only one argument, the `beginIndex` and this one extracts from `beginIndex` to the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

The empty String ("" with length 0) is a valid String. So that is what is returned by your code.

In other words `str.substring(str.length()-1);` returns the string "e", and `str.substring(str.length());` returns the empty string. Perfectly valid.

Answer (score -1):

Assume you got a String:

```
Hello World
```

this is what the indicies look like:

```
H e l l o   W o r l  d
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

"Hello World" has length of 11 so str.length would be equal to 11 in this case

now there is no index 11 in there, in fact 11 is beyond the last index. thats why you receive a IndexOutOfBounds

Additionally str.substring(number) returns a substring STARTING from the specified number all the way to the end of the string.

so str.substring(4) in this case would return

```
o World
```

Just thought i should put that in here