# What is difference between these 2 lines?

Tags: string, substring

```
String s = "coding";

System.out.println(s.substring(6));  // Line 1

System.out.println(s.charAt(6));    // Line 2
```

Why does line 1 print the empty string and not throw an error (index out of bound) like line 2 or vice versa?

Comment: You should add the primary language tag.  Then you can flag this comment 'no longer needed'.

Comment: Seems to be java. You may want to look at the source code https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java. but 6-6=0 may explain your question on substring. But don't think it's really worth, charAt and substring are totally different function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What will be the output of String.substring(String.length)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55702389/what-will-be-the-output-of-string-substringstring-length)

Answer (score 0):

The call to `s.substring(6)` starts at the very end of the string input `coding`, and therefore is legitimate, but just returns an empty string as the result.  However, `s.charAt(6)` is trying to refer to a character index out of bounds for the string input:

```
[c,o,d,i,n,g]
 0,1,2,3,4,5  6 <-- 6 is out of bounds
```

Note that the following call does generate a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```java
System.out.println(s.substring(7));  // throws an exception
```

In this case, we are trying to *start* the substring operation at a character index which is out of bounds, so it fails with an exception.